# Switch json data file

Tags: windows-phone-8

I would like to switch my json file that contains the data for my app based on the language selected.

Basically that would mean changing the  data uri to point to the new uri when the language is changed:

Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json");

I am using the below switch for this purpose:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

        string locale = ci.ToString();

        switch (locale)
        {
            case "fr":
                {
                    Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleDataFrench.json");

                    break;
                }

            case "en":
                {
                    Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleDataEnglish.json");
                }
        }
```

I get the error: "The name 'dataUri'does not exist in the current context. What  am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *Sunil Kumar S C* is right, the dataUri you define only work inside the case.

Another advice about your code is you might be better not use a switch case to do that because when you need support one new culture you need change the code.

You could directly append the culture after the file name, and use the default culture if the specific culture file is not exist. So you only need add a new file when you want to support more cultures, and no code need be changed.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
string locale = ci.ToString();
Uri dataUri = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.{0}.json", ci.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey its just an accessibility error. You were defining the dataUri locally for cases. U should do like this.
           Hope this help. Thanks

```
       Uri dataUri = null;
       switch (locale)
       {
            case "fr":
                {
                    dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleDataFrench.json");
                    break;
                }
            case "en-US":
                {
                    dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleDataEnglish.json");
                    break;
                }
       }
       //You can access it now --- dataUri
```

Answer (score 0):

the Uri variable dataUri = null; This variable is in the area published in **public sealed class ItemPage: Page**

deserialize the json content